# Efficient reduction of an R vector to a summary vector

Tags: performance, r, vector, reduction

I'm trying to do simulation of a sequence, which is of length N (varies between 10k and 3M) represented by a vector which has n 1's and s 0's where N = n+s.

I'd like to reduce this to a vector on the form c( 137, 278, 21271, 124162, ... ) where the numbers are the number of consecutive 1's in the original vector. Since I need to do this ~100,000 times for the simulation I'm doing I'm looking for as efficient a method as possible!

Thanks!

Martin

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by putting the vector in that form?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich - I'm trying to estimate the probabilities of certain lengths of 1's and 0's given different values, and I'm too bad at probability theory to calculate the exact answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `rle` to get that

```
x <- sample(c(1, 0), size = 3e+06, replace = TRUE)
x.rle <- rle(x)
x.rle
## Run Length Encoding
##   lengths: int [1:1499270] 4 1 2 3 4 1 1 3 1 4 ...
##   values : num [1:1499270] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 ...

vectorOf1 <- x.rle$lengths[x.rle$values == 1]
vectorOf2 <- x.rle$lengths[x.rle$values == 0]

head(vectorOf1, 20)
##  [1] 1 3 1 3 4 3 1 1 1 4 4 2 3 1 1 4 1 1 1 1

head(vectorOf2, 20)
##  [1] 4 2 4 1 1 1 1 5 2 2 2 1 3 3 7 2 1 1 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rle` function is the usual manner for doing this.